# Snack bar or confirm pop up. Which feedback is better when users delete their message?

Tags: delete

When users delete their message on the chatting screen like slack message thread, which feedback is better among snack bar and confirm pop up?

When I delete a e-mail message from Gmail, snack bar is provided involving button that enable to cancel deleting a email.

But snack bar is also useful on the chatting screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL; DR

For non-critical applications like a chat/messenger, snackbar is a better option as it isn't intrusive but at the same time, has the option of undoing the action.

**Detailed breakdown**

There's a logical difference between the two approaches

### Confirmation pop-up is a pre-action check

It gives the user a second chance of making a decision and works well for destructive actions (like deletion). However, it is also considered as an obstructive approach, so it doesn't work well with non-critical and fast-paced modern applications like chat/messenger apps.

### Snackbar is a notification alternative with post-action reversal

Snackbars are used more like a low-key notification tray that allows the user to quickly review or reverse their actions. In certain cases, it's impossible to reverse the action if the snackbar gets dismissed. While, in case of Gmail, the deleted email goes to the Deleted folder. It works well for non-critical applications where you want to inform the user about the action and the emphasis is not on confirmation or undoing of the action.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment.